# Webcam into Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, webcam, slick.js

I'm working with Slick Slider to generate a dynamic form using templates and one of them contains a webcam plugin.

Everything works but for example, if the slide 4 contains the webcam template, the page asks me if I want to disable or enable my webcam at the very beginning on the slide 0.

**So, here is a way to load the webcam plugin WHEN I'm on the slide 4 (or 5...) for example ?**

I tried to use JQuery method .hasClass but it's not working:

```
if ($('div.slick-slide').hasClass('slick-active') == true) {
enableWebcam();}
```

Comment: what does the `enableWebcam`does look like ? which plugin do you use and how? There are a lot of way to call them only when the time is 4pm and that you're in the correct location on earth, and that the weather is ok at the far side, but we need to see more of your code in order to help you.

Comment: I'm using webcam.js and `enableWebcam` is used to initialize the plugin (widht, height...). I was just thinking about adding a class `webcam` to the slide when my template is generated. And then, when I'm pressing on the next arrow, check if the next slide contains a class called `webcam` and if yes, enable the webcam plugin.

Comment: well your code doesn't reflect this idea at all, which should work btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix it, here is what I've done :

1. When the template with the webcam plugin (webcam.js) is generated, I added a class called `webcamPlugin` to the slide.
2. I added a function `afterChange` to check if the ID of the current slide, so `div.slick-active div.row`, has the same ID as the slide with the webcamPlugin.
3. If yes, I enable the webcam plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the slick.js `onBeforeChange` event to react when the relevant slide is active:

```
$('.your-slides-class').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if (nextSlide == 3) {
    enableWebcam();
  }
});
```

Notice that the slides index starts at 0, so "nextSlide ==3" refers to the fourth slide.
Also, off course you should replace the ".your-slides-class" with... the class or id with which you initiate your slider

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, the webcam template is generated so it can be on the slide 4 as it might be on the slide 1. That's why I can't use a fix if condition ^^. So for now, i'm trying to check if the next slide contains the webcam by using a class name but it's quite dificult to implement.

Comment: upload a JSFiddle with your code and we'll be able to examine it